# How to repeat same merge field multiple time in aspose?

Tags: aspose, aspose.words, aspose.pdf

Hi I have a scenario where i have list of locations. In my document i have merge field location_num. I want to print all location_num values in my doc dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can meet this requirement by using [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/products/words).

Please refer to the following section of Aspose.Words' documentation:
[How to Execute Mail Merge](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/How+to+Execute+Mail+Merge)

Here is sample code:

```
Document doc = new Document(filePath);
doc.MailMerge.Execute(GetDataTable());
doc.Save(MyDir + @"16.10.0.docx");
```

and the definition of GetDataTable method

```
private static DataTable GetDataTable()
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("table");

    dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("location_num"));

    DataRow dataRow;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
        dataRow[0] = "location value " + i;
        dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
    }

    return dataTable;
}
```

Hope, this helps. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Is that java code ? I am not getting dataTable.Columns or dataTable.Rows options.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below [Aspose.Words for Java](http://www.aspose.com/products/words/java) code to achieve the same:

```
import com.aspose.words.*;
import com.aspose.words.net.System.Data.DataColumn;
import com.aspose.words.net.System.Data.DataRow;
import com.aspose.words.net.System.Data.DataTable;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        License lic = new License();
        lic.setLicense("D:\\temp\\Aspose.total.java.lic");

        Document doc = new Document("D:\\temp\\input.docx");
        doc.getMailMerge().execute(GetDataTable());
        doc.save("D:\\temp\\16.10.0.docx");
    }

    private static DataTable GetDataTable()
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("table");
        dataTable.getColumns().add("location_num");

        DataRow dataRow;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            dataRow = dataTable.newRow();
            dataRow.set(0, "location value " + i);
            dataTable.getRows().add(dataRow);
        }

        return dataTable;
    }
}
```

Hope, this helps. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: This solution is working but there is a small problem, it's adding new page for each iteration. What's my requirement is that, on same page i want to add this merge field line by line if page is full then only it should add new page not on each iteration.  thanks :)

Comment: You need to use [Mail Merge with Regions](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsjava/How+to+Execute+Mail+Merge#HowtoExecuteMailMerge-HowtoExecuteMailMergewithRegions) functionality of Aspose.Words e.g. doc.getMailMerge().executeWithRegions(GetDataTable()); I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: That's not working - it's not replacing merge fields.

Comment: We need to test this scenario on our end; and since you can't attach files in this forum, please post your documents and code in [Aspose.Words forum](https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.words-product-family/75/showforum.aspx). Please zip and attach your 1) input, 2) Aspose.Words generated output Word documents and 3) source code in your thread for testing. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.